# Javascript: what is the purpose of a static method ex: Class.method

Tags: javascript, prototype

I've seen this asked but I still don't understand the purpose of a static declaration of a method.

```
class Dog {
   constructor(breed) {
     this.breed = breed;
   }

}
```

The below is part I don't understand the true difference:

```
Dog.color = function () {
    return "black";
}
```

vs

```
Dog.prototype.color = function () {
    return "brown";
}
```

I understand that the protype function allows the method `color` to be called on whatever instance I created.  Ex:  `var foo = new Dog()` . `foo.color()`;
But what is use case of a static method though if it can't be called on instances of the class?

Comment: The only reason to use one would be to call it on objects that would themselves be classes. Like `[class {static color(){return "red";}, class {static color(){return "blue";}}]`. There are a few other legitimate uses. That said, most static members are just instances of bad code written by people who don't understand JavaScript and should be replaced by standalone functions.

Comment: is it better practice to add the method inside the class definition or to make it a prototype method outside of the class definition?

Comment: @LionelYang inside if you can (ES2015+ or using a transpiler)